# Printing UWP native controls across multiple pages with overflow content

Tags: c#, .net, printing, uwp, uielement

In UWP (Universal Windows Platform), printing native controls is currently limited to displaying only one framework element per page. This constraint prevents the desired functionality of carrying overflow content from one page to another when using controls like Grid or StackPanel.

I tried using RichTextBlock, which was helpful in carrying overflow of text content. However, when using InlineUIContainer to include UIElements within the RichTextBlock, the overflow content wasn't carried down to the next page. Instead, it was abruptly stripped, resulting in cut-off text and data loss.

I have been working on this issue for several days without finding a solution. Is there any other method or approach that allows printing of UWP native controls, especially those that are lengthy and span more than one page? I need a way to track the overflow and ensure it is properly taken to the next page. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could please provide a code snip to help us further check the problem for you?